# Want to toggle 2 different list on click of two different button with same java script code

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Issues**
*There are following issues which are as follows :*

- First list is working fine but it has **problem** that **bullets** disappears on clcik of button - I know it can be **solved** by using `.Card1.short>li:nth-child(n + 6){display: block;}` only **but** I **need** to **hide** lists **tag** by **default**
- Second issue is that **second button** is not working on its own list but **changing first one** - I need to used same **single JS** as there can be more than **10 lists** . Also the `innerHTML` of both **buttons** works fine as **changes individually on click**

**Code**

```js
function reed(saad) {
  var ul = document.getElementById("Card1");
  button = document.getElementById("demo1");
  ul.classList.toggle("short");
  if (saad.innerHTML == "Show More") {
    saad.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  } else {
    saad.innerHTML = "Show More";
  }
}
```

```css
.Card1.short > li:nth-child(n + 6) {
  display: block;
}
.Card1 > li:nth-child(n + 6) {
  display: none;
}
ul{float:left;}
```

```html
<ul class="Card1" id="Card1">
  <li>Windows 10</li>
  <li>8GB Ram</li>
  <li>1TB SSD</li>
  <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
  <li>NVIDIA GeForce</li>
  <li>Full HD Display</li>
  <li>Dolby Audio</li>
  <li>1 Warranty</li>
  <button id="demo1" onclick="reed(this)">Show More</button>
</ul>


<ul class="Card2" id="Card2">
  <li>Windows 20</li>
  <li>16GB Ram</li>
  <li>10TB SSD</li>
  <li>Intel Core i15 (21th Gen)</li>
  <li>NVIDIA</li>
  <li>Double HD Display</li>
  <li>Dolby Audio</li>
  <li>2 Warranty</li>
  <button id="demo2" onclick="reed(this)">Show More</button>
</ul>
```

Comment: because you are addressing first ul on second `show more` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, which points to the parent element of the button, rather than using a fixed id. Also in the css, "list-item" rather than "block" will keep the bullets.

```
function reed(saad) {
    saad.parentElement.classList.toggle("short");
    if (saad.innerHTML == "Show More") {
        saad.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    } else {
        saad.innerHTML = "Show More";
    }
}
```

```
<ul class="Card" id="Card1">
    <li>Windows 10</li>
    <li>8GB Ram</li>
    <li>1TB SSD</li>
    <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
    <li>NVIDIA GeForce</li>
    <li>Full HD Display</li>
    <li>Dolby Audio</li>
    <li>1 Warranty</li>
    <button id="demo1" onclick="reed(this)">Show More</button>
</ul>


<ul class="Card" id="Card2">
    <li>Windows 20</li>
    <li>16GB Ram</li>
    <li>10TB SSD</li>
    <li>Intel Core i15 (21th Gen)</li>
    <li>NVIDIA</li>
    <li>Double HD Display</li>
    <li>Dolby Audio</li>
    <li>2 Warranty</li>
    <button id="demo2" onclick="reed(this)">Show More</button>
</ul>
```

```
.Card.short > li:nth-child(n + 6) {
    display: list-item;
}
.Card > li:nth-child(n + 6) {
    display: none;
}
ul{float:left;}
```

Check this fiddle if you want to generate the cards using javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/anixiapetha/o7fyjcnL/2/

Comment: Thanks brother. Bro what if button is out of `ul` tag. Then what to use

Comment: Then I would rather pass the id through to the function in the onclick, for example onclick="reed(this, 'Card1')" for the first one and in reed get the element for that id by using document.getElementById.

Comment: Then bro we have to use differently for every card

Comment: If you want it more generic, it might be better to create the lists using javascript or some kind of framework like react etc.

Comment: bro can you tell about this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813275/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-wishlist-type-that-if-heart-is-toggled-than-data-is-di

Comment: Bro what if we want to toggle child element instead of parent element then what will come in code `saad.parentElement.classList.toggle("short")` @Johan

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your code. Instead of selecting an element by `id`, use `this` to get parentElement and toggle the class `short`.

Also if you want the list marked with bullet, use `display:list-item`. The [`list-item`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-list-item) keyword causes the element to generate a ::marker pseudo-element box.

```js
function reed(saad) {
  saad.parentElement.classList.toggle("short");
  if (saad.innerHTML == "Show More") {
    saad.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  } else {
    saad.innerHTML = "Show More";
  }
}
```

```css
.Card1.short > li:nth-child(n + 6), .Card2.short > li:nth-child(n + 6) {
  display: list-item;
}

.Card1 > li:nth-child(n + 6), .Card2 > li:nth-child(n + 6) {
  display: none;
}

ul{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Card1" id="Card1">
  <li>Windows 10</li>
  <li>8GB Ram</li>
  <li>1TB SSD</li>
  <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
  <li>NVIDIA GeForce</li>
  <li>Full HD Display</li>
  <li>Dolby Audio</li>
  <li>1 Warranty</li>
  <button id="demo1" onclick="reed(this)">Show More</button>
</ul>


<ul class="Card2" id="Card2">
  <li>Windows 20</li>
  <li>16GB Ram</li>
  <li>10TB SSD</li>
  <li>Intel Core i15 (21th Gen)</li>
  <li>NVIDIA</li>
  <li>Double HD Display</li>
  <li>Dolby Audio</li>
  <li>2 Warranty</li>
  <button id="demo2" onclick="reed(this)">Show More</button>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks bro very much